# How to pass varaiable in HTML functions through jquery

Tags: html, jquery

this is my html code. `group.participants` is an array.

```
result +=`<button class="gsb-${group.id}" onclick="demo(${group.participants})">`+"DEMO"+`</button><br/>`;
```

this is my simple javascript code to display the array from the parameter

```
 function demo(participants){
            alert(participants);
        }
```

this shows me the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

may I know what is the problem

Comment: `Unexpected end of input` is likely unrelated to the code you've provided, but can be easily tested by removing the php(?) parts, eg `result +=\`<button>DEMO</button><br/>\`;` to see if you still get the same error.  If you don't then it will be caused by the content (actual values) of `group.participants` (or, less likely, `group.id`)

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery you can use the following to pass data to a selector

```
$(`.gsb-${group.id}`).data(group.participants);
```

to recover it you just have to call data() method

```
$(`.gsb-${group.id}`).data();
```

Finally like each group have different participants, you will have to append first the group button before add the data to it

```
result.append(`<button class="gsb-${group.id}" onclick="demo(${group.id})">`+"DEMO"+`</button><br/>`);
$(`.gsb-${group.id}`).data(group.participants);
```

```js
    function demo(groupId) {
       var participants = $(`.gsb-${groupId}`).data();
       console.log(participants);
    }


    var result = $('#result');
    var group = {
      id:1,
      participants:[
        {name:'test1'},
        {name:'test2'}
     ]
    }
    result.append(`<button class="gsb-${group.id}" onclick="demo(${group.id})">`+"DEMO"+`</button><br/>`);
    $(`.gsb-${group.id}`).data(group.participants);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: yeah I'm using jqery and it's not working

Comment: Well, you cleary said that `participants` is an array, so you will need to expand your array first e.g. `data-participants="${group.participants.join(',')}"`

Comment: If you're using [tag:jquery] then use `$(this).data("participants")` - and use jquery event binding rathee than onclick - will save you a *ton* of headaches trying to get onclick= to work.